# Date on posts is updated after another post is added ja JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Currently I am doing a small school project, its a forum where you can add posts, see the date when it was added, sort by date, etc.

My problem here is when the post is added, it always update the latest date on every post (see on screenshot, time between adding them is few minutes)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJCaZ.png)

```
    const date = new Date();
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let minute = date.getMinutes();
    let second = date.getSeconds();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();


    postsView.innerHTML += `<div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p> ${title} [${day}-${month}-${year}, ${hour}:${minute}:${second} AM]: ${description}
          <a href="#" onclick="deletePost('${title}')" class="btn btn-danger ml-5">Delete</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>`;
```

I tried with:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

but the result is the same.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define an onClick function for your button to add posts and then update the content in that function.

```js
const handleAddPost = (title, description) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const hour = date.getHours();
  const minute = date.getMinutes();
  const second = date.getSeconds();
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  const postsView = document.getElementById("post-view");

  postsView.innerHTML += `<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p> ${title} [${day}-${month}-${year}, ${hour}:${minute}:${second} AM]: ${description}
      <a href="#" onclick="deletePost('${title}')" class="btn btn-danger ml-5">Delete</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>`;
}
```

```js
<div>
  <div id="post-view"></div>
  <button onclick="handleAddPost('${title}', '${description}')">Add Post</button>
</div>
```